# Get last month date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WHERE ap_CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

the above query will return the last/previous month, however its missing 2 records from the last day of the last month (2022-04-30) due to the date including a time range:

```
2022-04-30 09:16:00.000
2022-04-30 19:11:02.907
```

I'm currently manually pulling the dates

```
where ap_CreatedDate >= '2022-04-01' and ap_CreatedDate < '2022-05-01'
```

but I want to automate this process, any help will be much obliged

Comment: Relevant https://sqlblog.org/dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest and least error prone way to do this is as follows:

- Use greater then equals `>=` for the lower limit
- Use less than `<` for the upper limit, and make that limit the first of the next month

```
WHERE ap_CreatedDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2))
AND ap_CreatedDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

- Don't use `between` because its not intuitive what it covers and you can end up with this issue

Comment: thanks for getting back so quickly, worked a treat!

Comment: The one everyone always forgets: the second parameter of `EOMONTH`. I still haven't worked out why there isn't a `SOMONTH` function